# Adding event to calendar shows wrong end date

Tags: android, datetime, android-calendar

I want to add an event in the calendar programmatically. I am using below code to create and calendar event.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, DateUtils.getMiliseconds("10/10/2017", "09:02 AM");
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, DateUtils.getMiliseconds("10/13/2017", "05:02 PM"));
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "my title");
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "my location" );
startActivity(intent);
```

Here `DateUtils.getMiliseconds` is my method below.

```
static long getMiliseconds(String date, String time){

    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(date+" "+time);
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date1);
        Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        beginCal.set(cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        return beginCal.getTimeInMillis();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

Here, I am using same method to get milliseconds for both start time and end time. I am getting correct start time in calendar event as 10/10/2017  9:02 AM. But end time is 10/10/2017 10:02 AM instead of 10/13/2017 5:02 PM.

I have tried solutions for far available on stackoverflow but none of the solutions work for me.

I also tried passing `Events.DTSTART` and `Events.DTSTART` instead of `EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME` and `EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME` but it shows wrong date too.

Comment: I used Date today = new Date(getMiliseconds("10/13/2017", "05:02 PM")); and it gave me a smooth Fri Oct 13 17:02:36 CEST 2017 printed with no problem at all. (Eclipse Java IDE)

Comment: Confirmed: intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, new Date(getMiliseconds("10/10/2017", "09:02 AM")));
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, new Date(getMiliseconds("10/13/2017", "05:02 PM")));

   Works perfectly fine and manages intents with no problem on Android 5.x and 6.x (Android Studio IDE)

intent result: Bundle[{endTime=Fri Oct 13 17:02:17 GMT+00:00 2017, beginTime=Tue Oct 10 09:02:17 GMT+00:00 2017, eventLocation=my location, title=my title}]

Comment: It's working perfectly fine on version 6.0 but not on 5.1. Is there any solution for this? @koksalb

Comment: I will take a look into it tonight and let you know if I can find some major changes between versions - date libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your `getMiliseconds` method, the time in milliseconds it is returning seems to be correct. This looks like an issue where Google Calendar, where it is ignoring your parameter for the `endTime` and using the default "`startTime` + 1 hour" as the `endTime` value.

Check this Google's issue tracker: [Google Calendar does not respect event start and end times received via intent](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37011823). It seems that the issue was because of a bug in the stock calendar app for devices running some version of Android 5.0. It worked fine for Android 4.4.4.

For most of them updating the app to the latest version fixed the issue and for others uninstalling the updates for calendar application on your phone made it fine. Try the above 2 options for the device you are testing on. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine on version 6.0 but not on 5.1. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: There is a solution given but I am not sure if it works. Worth a shot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942177/1306419. Since seemed like it was a bug on OS / Calendar app side, only an update to them could fix it. As I said in the answer, one thing to try is to go to the `App info` for the `Calendar` app, and look for option called `Uninstall Updates`. It will either be a button or will be in the menu options. Try and use that to get it working on your device. If that doesn't work make sure your Calendar app is latest and up to date with play store hoping that that version fixed the bug.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues. I guess re-installing calendar works. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Try it:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Hope it help

Comment: Nope. Still the same results.